# find logic that calls a known Azure function with Resource Graph Explorer

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-graph

I need to change the logic apps that use a certain azure function because it was moved.
How do I find which Logic apps use this azure function?

it should be a query in Azure Resource Graph Explorer but I am not familiar with the syntax.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Find logic that calls a known Azure function with Resource Graph Explorer: -

To find the logic app that uses your function/function app, you can use either of the below queries which satisfies your requirement.

*Approach-1:*

```
resources
| where type == 'microsoft.logic/workflows'
| where properties.definition.actions contains "Provide your function app/function name"
| project logicapp = name
```

[image]

*Approach-2:*

```
resources
| where type == 'microsoft.logic/workflows'
| extend workflowDefinition = parse_json(properties.definition)
| mv-expand trigger = workflowDefinition.triggers
| where tostring(trigger) contains 'Apiconnection' and tostring(trigger) contains "Provide your function app/function name"
| project logicapp = name, id
```

[image]